# Chinese font of CTEX

Tags: beamer, fonts, chinese, ctex

I use the package of CTEX to enbale the Chinese in beamer, but I found the font does not show in my setting.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ctex}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{}
  这是一段中文文本。
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beamer uses the sans serif font, so set \setsansfont

Comment: To concretize Ulrike's suggestion: use `\setCJKsansfont{SimSun}`.